# Unable to Run YouCompleteMe in neovim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim, youcompleteme

I use Manjaro (5.6.7 Kernel), I am trying to install YCM on neovim. I did it before, but it was vim, and I used vundle, this time I am using vim-plug. I get this message when I launch newvim.

> YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (3.5.1+) support.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the [python-pynvim](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/python-pynvim/) package installed? Can you run `:py3 print('hello')` from inside NeoVim?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

YouCompleteMe breaks so often, that I wrote down the steps to resurrect it:

**1. Attempt reinstalling YCM:**

```
$ python <DOTFILE_PATH>/vim/plugged/youcompleteme/install.py --clang-completer
```

**2. Received the following error?**

> ERROR: found static Python library (/Users/USER/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin/libpython3.7m.a) but a dynamic one is required.

Then:

```
$ export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework"
$ pyenv install 3.7.2
```

**3. If neovim throws error** *"[...] requires Vim compiled with Python (2.7.1+ or 3.4+) support"* **on start, then:**

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pynvim
```

Replace `3.7.2` with your *actual* python3 version. No need to stick to an old version, just because I wrote this note a while back.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. In my case I was missing the `pynvim` package in my virtualenv.